# Stability Analysis of DFE in terms of R0 Using Ruth-Hurwitz Criterion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, stability-in-odes, biology, mathematical-biology

I am working with an epidemiological model in the form of a dynamical system of seven ODEs and I am trying to show that the DFE is stable if R0<1. When applying the Routh-Hurwitz criterion, I see that one of the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial cannot be rewritten in terms of R0 (so that the coefficient is positive when R0<1). I tried to manipulate this coefficient in several ways, but end up getting another condition for that coefficient to be positive apart from R0<1. So, I just wanted to know if this is allowed or if I am doing something wrong. Also, I want to confirm that I checked my computations and simplifications several times, so I am certain that I am not doing any simplification errors. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment. So, I have a characteristic polynomial of degree 4 where the coefficients a_0 and a_1 are clearly positive unconditionally. To establish the Routh-Hurwitz criterion, I need to show that a_2, a_3, and a_4 are also positive when R0<1. I was able to rewrite a_2 and a_4 in terms of R0 and show that those two coefficients are positive when R0<1. The trouble is with a_3 as I get another condition involving the parameters (i.e., alpha1+gamma2<eta1+gamma3) for the coefficient to be positive.

Comment: Please refer to the "Local stability in terms of the basic reproduction number" section of the paper, https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11071-022-07235-7 as it is similar to what I am trying to do.

Comment: How have you found your basic reproduction number?  The next generation matrix, some other method?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment! Yes, I found R0 using the NGM method as well as the endemic equilibrium method. They both produced the same expression for R0.